# I have a table in a database in plesk that I think has over 90,000 entries. When I click on browse/refresh it keeps showing different row totals

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, plesk

I have a table in a database in plesk that I think has over 90,000 entries.  When I click on browse/refresh in phpMyAdmin it keeps showing different row totals.

One field in the table has a timestamp, so I can check what is being added. I'm not seeing any records being added or removed.  The 'total rows' jumps up and down by a factor of about 20%.  I've renamed the table and it still does it.  Nothing is accessing / using it.  Is it an issue with table sizes?  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't follow, you say 90000 entries and then talk about row totals..do you have a query which sums/counts rows? and where are you seeing this total?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.